# How to use jQuery - Inputmask plugin for this '###.##.abc,22'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, maskedtextbox

Do anyone have an idea about implementing the following behaviour using the Input mask plugin of jQuery like if we want `###.##.abc,22`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/